# in a word macro delete everything that does not start with one of two strings

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a data file that contains a lot of extra data.  I want to run a word macro that only keeps 5 lines (I could live with 6 if it makes it easier)

I found how to delete a row if it contains a string.

I want to keep the paragraphs that start with:

1. Record write time
2. Headband impedance
3. Headband Packets
4. Headband RSSI
5. Headband Status

I could live with keeping

6. Headband ID

I tried the following macro, based on a sample I saw here.  But, I am getting an error.

```
Sub test()
'
' test Macro
Dim search1 As String
search1 = "record"
Dim search2 As String
search2 = "headb"
Dim para As Paragraph
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
     Dim txt As String
     txt = para.Range.Text
If Not InStr(LCase(txt), search1) Then
     If Not InStr(LCase(txt), search2) Then
   para.Range.Delete
End If
Next
End Sub
```

The error is: next without For.

I know that there may be a better way, and an open to any fix.

Sample data: 
The data is:

```
ZEO Start data record
----------------
Record write time: 10/14/2014 20:32
Factory reset date: 10/14/2014 20:23
Headband ID: 01/01/1970 18:32
Headband impedance: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 241 247 190 165 154 150 156 162 177 223 202
Headband Packets: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 21 4 30 3 3 3 9 4 46 46 1
Headband RSSI: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 6 254 254 250 5 255 4 3 249
Headband Status: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 169 170 170
Hardware ID: 2
Software ID: 43
Sensor Life Reset date: Not recorded
sleep Stat Reset date: 10/14/2014 20:18
Awakenings: 0
Awakenings Average: 0
Start of night: 10/14/2014 20:28
End of night: 10/14/2014 20:32
Awakenings: 0
Awakenings Average: 0
Time in deep: 0
Time in deep average: 0
```

Comment: There was some formatting that got lost when I posted this, sorry about that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you got the formatting wrong, you can always edit your question, there is a button "edit" below it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `End If` missing. Add this immediately after the first `End If` - do you get the same error?

**Update:**
There is also an error in the `If` conditions. Check the [InStr reference](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_instr.asp) for return values.
You need to use something like `If Not InStr(...) = 1 Then` on both if statements.